# How can I get a MessageBox to show when a tabpage is selected?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried everything that I can think of and looked but nothing is working. I want a messageBox to appear when a user clicks the third tab page of my tab control if they are sure they want to go to that tab page. Any help?

Comment: You cannot prevent the tab from being selected while the Selecting event runs.  Avoid spamming the user with message boxes, I rarely not answer "yes, dammit!" on a useless 'are you zure' message.

Answer (score 6):

Handle the [`Selecting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selecting.aspx) event.  It is fired before the index is changed so you can cancel the change if you decide to do so.

```
private void myTabControl_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TabPageIndex == 2)
    {   // the third page is being selected
        var result = MessageBox.Show(
                         "Change to tab?",
                         "Change?",
                         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                         MessageBoxIcon.Question,
                         MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
        if (result == DialogResult.No)
            e.Cancel = true; // cancel it if the user said No
    }
}
```